# Ground zone in Proteus/Ares

Tags: proteus

I am doing the tracks for a PCB design. In the lab earlier when I put a ground zone over the board all of the connections that had to go to ground disappeared, as expected... it made me happy.

Now I get home and try to do the same because for reason it disappeared and it does nothing to any of the ground connections. I was just wondering if I have missed some step.

At the moment I press "zone mode" and default is selected in the traces list. I then draw it over my PCB design. Under the settings I select bottom copper and ground then press ok. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this isn't a direct answer to the question because it's based on my experience using other software.

If it were PADs or OrCAD, you'd draw the area you wish to be flooded with copper pour (or copper), set the object so that it appeared on the correct layer and finally, you'd set that copper to have a net name. I think this may be what you have forgotten to do. Without a net name it is just node-less copper and won't do what you want. Maybe it's also on the wrong layer? Maybe you have two similar node names and you selected the wrong one?